# Bootstrap 4 drop-down menu in table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4

I have some trouble with a drop-down menu (Bootstrap 4). So I have a table:

[image]

When I'm clicking on settings in first row I have a drop-down:

[image]

But when I'm clicking on settings in second row, I have a drop-down in same place as the first. How I can solve it?

[image]

Here is a codepen same troubles there:
[CodePen](https://codepen.io/WhoIsDT/pen/RMoNEL)

HTML:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-hover table-sm">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Фио сотрудника</th>
                    <th>Должность</th>
                    <th>Телефон</th>
                    <th>Ломбард</th>
                    <th>Профиль доступа</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tflex">
                        <span class="default-av">hC</span>
                        <span>Тарнавский Дмитрий Алексеевич</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>Разработчик</td>
                    <td>+7 (921) 030-33-32</td>
                    <td>Южный</td>
                    <td>Администратор</td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <i class="far fa-cog"></i>
                            </a>    
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Разработчик</td>
                    <td>Moe</td>
                    <td>+7 (921) 030-33-32</td>
                    <td>Dooley</td>
                    <td>+7 (921) 030-33-32</td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <i class="far fa-cog"></i>
                            </a>    
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action2</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Use Unique *Ids* for both the dropdowns

Comment: i tried, no success

Comment: I tried on the Codepen Snippet and its working for me

Comment: we are talking about this:  <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button" id="link2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">

id right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated in the [Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/#responsive-tables)...

> **Vertical clipping/truncation** 
>   Responsive tables make use of overflow-y:
>   hidden, which clips off any content that goes beyond the bottom or top
>   edges of the table. In particular, this can clip off dropdown menus
>   and other third-party widgets.

It's happening because the **`table-responsive` doesn't have enough vertical height**. Give the `table-responsive` a min height, for example...

```
.vh-100 {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VXmLqG?editors=1100

Comment: Your codepen have some troubles.. i cant see it, it's always reload page..

So we detected, that main problem in responsive table. ok. I just tried to remove class table-resposive. Now i have troubles, that my ddmenu shows far away from right side of screen. also, when i reload page i need to click twice on element to open ddmenu.. How i can solve it? And second problem that i need to open/close ddmenu about 20 times, after what my ddmenu will shows on normal position... What it can be?

Comment: Same problem on my codepen: https://codepen.io/WhoIsDT/pen/RMoNEL. you can see it. i removed responsive talbe class and now i need to open/close few times, and by one time ddmenu moving from right to left for a few px. How to solve this bug?

Answer (score 6):

`data-toggle="dropdown" data-boundary="window"`

The code above did the trick for me!

Here is my complete dropdown in table cell code:

```html
<div class="btn-group d-md-none m-1">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"
    type="button"
    id="dropdownMenuButton"
    data-toggle="dropdown"
    data-boundary="window"
    aria-haspopup="true"
    aria-expanded="false">
    <span>Actions</span>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown item</a>
  </div>
</div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 2):

Define this properties for Bootstrap 4. Good Luck!

```
data-toggle="dropdown" data-boundary="window"
```

Comment: Be specific of where to add this please. Does it go on the anchor tag or the actual dropdown DIV?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Working fiddle

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-hover table-sm">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Фио сотрудника</th>
                <th>Должность</th>
                <th>Телефон</th>
                <th>Ломбард</th>
                <th>Профиль доступа</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="tflex">
                    <span class="default-av">hC</span>
                    <span>Тарнавский Дмитрий Алексеевич</span>
                </td>
                <td>Разработчик</td>
                <td>+7 (921) 030-33-32</td>
                <td>Южный</td>
                <td>Администратор</td>
                <td align="center">
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            <i class="far fa-cog"></i>
                        </a>    
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Разработчик</td>
                <td>Moe</td>
                <td>+7 (921) 030-33-32</td>
                <td>Dooley</td>
                <td>+7 (921) 030-33-32</td>
                <td align="center">
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            <i class="far fa-cog"></i>
                        </a>    
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action2</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
                    <tr>
                <td>Разработчик</td>
                <td>Moe</td>
                <td>+7 (921) 030-33-32</td>
                <td>Dooley</td>
                <td>+7 (921) 030-33-32</td>
                <td align="center">
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            <i class="far fa-cog"></i>
                        </a>    
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action2</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
                    <tr>
                <td>Разработчик</td>
                <td>Moe</td>
                <td>+7 (921) 030-33-32</td>
                <td>Dooley</td>
                <td>+7 (921) 030-33-32</td>
                <td align="center">
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink4" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            <i class="far fa-cog"></i>
                        </a>    
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action2</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Разработчик</td>
                <td>Moe</td>
                <td>+7 (921) 030-33-32</td>
                <td>Dooley</td>
                <td>+7 (921) 030-33-32</td>
                <td align="center">
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink7" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            <i class="far fa-cog"></i>
                        </a>    
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action2</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LSKhan/yopp45kq/)

Comment: maybe i'm something missing? even on codepen when i'm changing id's nothing happen...

Comment: check last element of table in your fiddle

Comment: you can identify corrections. i guess your question is answered in this fiddle