# Bootstrap 4 dropdown not-visible inside datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

I have seen [Bootstrap button drop-down inside responsive table not visible because of scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26018756/bootstrap-button-drop-down-inside-responsive-table-not-visible-because-of-scroll) and this [Bootstrap 4 drop-down menu in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49346755/bootstrap-4-drop-down-menu-in-table) question but the solutions does not work with me because I'm using the DataTables plugin.

[image]

The dropdown menu should be above everything, but even after using `data-boundary="window"` as the Bootstrap 4 documentation tells, it still does not work.

You can see the problem in this **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skoz7tjb/)**.

Without the code of DataTables, it works just fine.

```
$(table).DataTable(
{
    'bPaginate'         : true,
    'bLengthChange'     : false,
    'bFilter'           : true,
    'bInfo'             : true,
    'bAutoWidth'        : false,
    'aoColumnDefs'      : [
      {
        'bSortable'     : false,
        'aTargets'      : ['nosorting']
      }],
    'aaSorting'         : [],
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an overflow on your data table. So to make your dropdown visible, you need to append it to the body. [**Solution**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31029300/how-to-append-a-single-dropdown-menu-to-body-in-bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

Just added in datatable configuration 'scrollY': '50vh', 'scrollCollapse': true

```js
$(function() {
  var table = $('table');

  $(table).DataTable({
    'bPaginate': true,
    'bLengthChange': false,
    'bFilter': true,
    'bInfo': true,
    'bAutoWidth': false,
    'aoColumnDefs': [{
      'bSortable': false,
      'aTargets': ['nosorting']
    }],
    'aaSorting': [],
  })
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.1/umd/popper.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Options</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>John</td>
              <td>
                <div class="btn-group dropup">
                  <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Title
            <span class="caret"></span>
          </a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a>Option 1</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a>Option 1</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group dropleft">
                  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle font-10-px" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" data-boundary="window">Options</button>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <button class="dropdown-item font-12-px" type="button">Option 1</button>
                    <button class="dropdown-item font-12-px" type="button">Option 2</button>
                    <button class="dropdown-item font-12-px" type="button">Option 3</button>
                    <button class="dropdown-item font-12-px" type="button">Option 4</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want the dropdown above everything, I don't want it to scroll.

Comment: Still doesn't work. If I copy and paste exactly your code into the JSFiddle the same bug happens, plus I want to maintain the `dropleft` behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Try This. I hope it will work. But please check this in mobile view. If you face responsive issue then give tabel-responsive class to its parent div.

```
.table-responsive, .dataTables_scrollBody {
   overflow: visible !important;
}
```